# Need to INSERT a row after a Form submission, based on column of another table (JOIN)

Tags: join, insert, bookmarks

I have a list of items, and I want my User to be able to bookmark an item.  They click on the button, and it needs to pass a 1 to the 'bookmark' table with the item ID. Right now my list of items is 64 rows.

I know $pid is passed to the query because the query below passes the ID of the selected item to all 64 items and creates 64 rows.

I just want it insert one row at a time.

```
        $query = "INSERT INTO a_item_bookmark (playerID,bookmark)
                    SELECT p.id, 1
                    FROM a_items p
                    WHERE p.id = '" . $pid . "'
                    ";
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT p.id FROM a_items p WHERE p.id = '" . $pid . "'. if i replace $pid with 1 then it will return 1 as p.id

so, following SQL query is more effective code then other Query="INSERT INTO a_item_bookmark (playerID,bookmark) values (" . $pid . ",1)";

Otherwise this would be your answer 
Query="INSERT INTO a_item_bookmark (playerID,bookmark) values ((select id from a_items p where p.id=1),1)";

Comment: That would only match the item with the ID of 1.  I need to INSERT the row that matches the ID of the item.

Comment: please clear expected output and share table schema

Comment: CREATE TABLE `a_item_bookmark` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bookmark` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `itemID` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userID` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)